# Get.back() and Get.snackbar() are not getting triggered: Flutter, GetX

Tags: flutter, rest, navigation, flutter-getx, snackbar

I am using GetX to show snackbar and for navigation. Based, on the API response, some snackbar is shown, but it does not get triggered. I checked by setting breakpoint. The lines of Get.back() and snackbar get executed, but nothing actually happens on screen.
Here is the code-

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      context.loaderOverlay.show();
                      Map<String, dynamic> result = await api.resetPassword(
                          email: _emailController.text,
                          otp: _otpController.text,
                          password: _passwordController.text);
                      context.loaderOverlay.hide();
                      String code = result[CODE];
                      if (code == '2000') {
                        Get.snackbar(
                          "Successful",
                          "Password has been reset successfully",
                          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
                          snackStyle: SnackStyle.FLOATING,
                          backgroundColor: snackbarBackgroundColor,
                          colorText: snackbarColorText,
                        );
                        Get.back();
                      } else {
                        Get.snackbar(
                          "Failed",
                          "Password reset failed",
                          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
                          snackStyle: SnackStyle.FLOATING,
                          backgroundColor: snackbarBackgroundColor,
                          colorText: snackbarColorText,
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: const FittedBox(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 2,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        'Reset Password',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 80,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

make the snackbar async using the await keyword before the snack bar
in this state its wait the snack bar view after it dispose the other function is run bemuse in your code it exit snack bar and Get.back() in same time make the function async

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck with the same issue, and after a lot of search, I found this work around which worked for me.

> Get.snackbar("title", "message");
>
> Get.key.currentState?.pop();